# Linked List syntax: is "next" already defined?

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, linked-list, definition

I am new in Data Structure.
I came up with a question when I was trying to write code using linked list using C++.

In linked list, is pointer `next`, `previous` defined by the compiler? Or we have to name our own and it does not matter how we call it?

Comment: You'll have to define it yourself.

Comment: *When we sit down to write programs, we become gods before our worlds, as long as we follow some rules: follow the standard, don't use global variables, and don't code without coffee.* (It's your choice, since you or someone else defined the data structure)

Comment: Under normal circumstances, you shouldn't be defining a linked list at all--you should use `std::list` instead (or, more often than not, `std::vector` or `std::deque` instead of using a linked list at all).

Comment: There's a predefined `std::next`, but that's a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`next` and `previous` are not predefined. We have to define it ourself. Usually for a single linked list, we come up with a node structure which consists of a data field and a`next` pointer which is a pointer to a node of the same type. A simple example is as follows:

```
struct node{
   int data;     //data part
   struct node *next;    // next pointer - points to a node of the same type
}
```